# How to model movement of a sideways scissor jack system, constrained on one side

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

I am trying to figure out how much the placement of connections for a scissor gear system (or sideways scissor jack system) can resist rotational motion from a force applied at one of those connections when the other is held in place.

If the force is applied to the right side with an offset side connection and the first joint is 1 and 2 (with the force F applied to joint 1), and joints 5 and 6 on the other side would be stationary save link rotation.  If the side connections terminate at the same point than force applied to the right side would be applied to joint 1 and joint 4 on the opposite side would be stationary. For the problem I am not moving the nuts that make up the scissor gear system and am treating them and the center screw as one entity that is ridged. Photos 1.1 and 2.1 show the different configurations, photos 1.2 and 2.2 show show what I think would happen when the force is applied while photos 1.3 and 2.3 show the FBD.

My current approach shows a reaction moment at the opposite side of the gear system to where the force is applied but that should be 0 since rotation is allowed. Since I cant sum the moments I cant use a static analysis to solve, so I am not exactly sure how to equate the two in order to show that more distance between the points on the edges gives more rotational resistance. Do I need to program a solution? What is the best way to go about molding / solving this?

Photo 1.1:
[image]

Photo 1.2:
[image]

Photo 1.3:
[image]

Photos 2.1:
[image]

Photos 2.2:
[image]

Photos 2.3:
[image]